# Javascript object keep contain the old data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to filter result from JSON string based on status selection. I will explain more in depth. In respect to below code, jsonstring contain the whole javascript object.I filter status by grep function and than i added result into main object(jsonstring) so i can get whole javascript object with new filter status. But each time this drop down called i am getting last updated javascript object but i want the original jsonstring each time this function call.

```
function dropdownchange(jsonstring)
{
 var e = document.getElementById("documents_filter");
 var svalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

 if(svalue == "In Progress")
 {
  var docstatusfilter;
  docstatusfilter = $.grep(jsonstring.Apps.statuslist , function(el, i) {
           return el.DOCUMENT_STATUS === "In Progress"        
            });   
    jsonstring.Apps.statuslist = docstatusfilter;   
 }

 if(svalue == "Auth (Verified)")
 {
  var authstatus;
  authstatus = $.grep(jsonstring.Apps.statuslist , function(el, i) {
           return el.DOCUMENT_STATUS === "Auth (Verified)"          
            });    
   jsonstring.Apps.statuslist = authstatus;    
 }

}
```

When this function call first time it works perfect but once i change dropdown it contain the previous record in jsonstring but i want the original jsonstring each time when this function call..

Anybody have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: (Not directly related to your problem, but why name a variable `jsonstring` when it doesn't contain JSON (or a non-JSON string)? It's easier to debug code that uses meaningful variable names.)

Comment: Thanks..i put as a sample..I can't put original code due to cmpny privacy. So i put jsonstring and i guess name doesn't make anysense.If you follow the rule of naming convention i guess you are fine..

Comment: OK, sure. Well given that `jsonstring` is an object, you need to remember that JS doesn't make copies of objects when they're passed as parameters or assigned to other variables, it passes/assigns a reference, so `jsonstring` refers to the _same_ object as whatever variable you were using outside `dropdownchange()` and any changes you make to `jsonstring` will be changing that same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is copy your jsonstring  into another object and use that object in your function. Here is a function that will clone your object -

```
function clone(obj) {
    var copy = jQuery.extend(true, {}, obj);
    return copy;
}
```

Now call this function like this :

```
function dropdownchange(jsonstring)
{
var newJsonString = clone(jsonstring);
 var e = document.getElementById("documents_filter");
 var svalue = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
 ......
 ....
```

just use `newJsonString` inside your function instead of `jsonstring`.

Comment: Thanks..I tried but still it doesnt work. i dont know why its still alter the jsonstring eventhough i am using newJsonString..Any suggestion?

Comment: It works now..I update clone function with your new one and it works..That is awesome!!. The other thing is i have whole json into "this" object and i am getting hard time to pass "this" into dropdown onchange event.Because "this" object is different meaning in dropdown change.any solution for that??

Comment: I am unable to understand your other problem. Can you please make it more clear?

Comment: I successfully got answer after copying object with your code. in my application i need to do 3 times copy of object so i just wonder is there any performance issue will happen down the road?

Answer (score 0):

Store the original string in a separate variable. Use the original string variable as your function's input and then set the resulting value to a different variable.

Comment: From the way it's being used, `jsonstring` is an object, not a string (and not JSON), so simply assigning it to another variable will result in both variables referencing the same object.

Comment: Thanks Doug.No i can't do that. As i have to render whole html based on that jsonstring and also there were plenty other reason which going on in my code. If you can give me any sample that would be great

Comment: Obviously you have to copy the object so there are two objects. The point is you can't edit an object and then expect to get it's original state back. You need to make a copy of the original state of the object and reference that original state.

Comment: Also, not really sure why you can't do that. if you're rendering a document just copy the object before you render it. I don't know what code sample I could give you - this question has a broader scope than programming as a whole: In order to have an original *copy* of something, you have to make that *copy* before you edit the original. The same is true of any kind of file or data editing.

Comment: I know its hard though.Thanks doug. I already copy the object before i pass into dropdown but still no result.  var c = new Object();
    for (var e in o) {
        c[e] = o[e];
    }
    return c;

Comment: Perhaps ravi can supply us with some more code. If you're getting a JSON response remotely, it would have to exist as a string somewhere. Perhaps you could store an original copy of the string before you start parsing/editing it. You'd have to re-parse the string every time you want the original copy though. Like I said, if you show us more of the context of what you're doing, perhaps we can come up with a different, more efficient approach to what you're doing that doesn't involve doing a deep copy of a massive object...